# Longest substring without repeating characters throwing a run time error?

Tags: javascript

**My code works for many other test cases except for [this](https://leetcode.com/submissions/detail/531439156/testcase/)**

It runs a runtime error so I was wondering if someone could help me figure out why. Thanks, here's the code:

```
    if(s.length <= 1){
        return s.length
    }
    let lengths = []
    s = s.split('')

function run(index){
    if(index === s.length){
        lengths.push(s.slice(0,index).length)
        return
    }
    if(s.slice(0,index).indexOf(s[index]) >= 0){
        lengths.push(s.slice(0,index).length)
        s.splice(0, s.slice(0,index).indexOf(s[index]))
        if( s.slice(0,index).indexOf(s[index]) === 0 ){
            s.splice(0,1)
        }
        index = 0
    
    }
    run(index+1)   
 }
    run(0)

    return Math.max(...lengths)
};
```

Comment: The link requires login. I skimmed your code, when you `splice` or in case there are duplicated characters, wouldn't `index` > `s.length`? It will cause infinite loop

Comment: Create a snippet with your failure test cases

Answer (score 0):

```
var lengthOfLongestSubstring = function(str) {
    if (str.length <=1){
        return str.length;
    }
    var _max = 0;
     do {
        var obj_ = {};
        var substrings = '';
        var l = str.length;
        //if (_max < l) - even i cannot add if condition here
        // it cause time limit problem
        for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
            if (!obj_[str[i]]) {
                obj_[str[i]] = 1;
            } else {
                obj_[str[i]] += 1;
            }
            if (obj_[str[i]] > 1) {
                break;
            } else {
                substrings += str[i];
            }
        }
        if (_max < substrings.length) {
            _max = substrings.length;
        }
        var str = str.substring(1, str.length);
    }
    while (str.length > 0);
    return _max;
};
```

This method only gives me output, others solutions gives me time limit exceeds.

LINK to input https://github.com/rinshankolayil/DUMMY_REPO/blob/main/leetcode/test_data.txt

**OUTPUT**

[image: OUTPUT]